# JS if statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, readonly, servicenow

I have a checkbox and if it is checked, I want text boxes to be editable.  If it remains unchecked, then I want the text boxes to be readOnly.  Here is my JS:

```
if (document.getElementById('itemize').checked==false) {
    document.getElementById('budget_1').readOnly = true;
} else  {
    document.getElementById('budget_1').readOnly = false;
     }
```

My HTML for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="itemize" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" />
```

The JS seems to make the text box readOnly just fine, but when I make sure the checkbox is checked, the text box remains readOnly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You spelled `budget` wrong on line 4.

Comment: Consider this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwny4tdp/  - It's your exact code and it works fine. Can you provide some context that may help us narrow down your specific issue, since it doesn't seem to be in the snippet you've provided.

Comment: When is your code execute? If it's executed only once when you load the page, obviously nothing will change when you check or uncheck the box. You would need to add a event listener (on the "change" event, probably) to update things.

Comment: @Santi Possibly the syntax error? Check the edit history.

Comment: @mhatch Yes, I pointed this out in my first comment, however OP pointed out to someone else (in a deleted answer) that it was *not* misspelled in his actual code, only in his posted example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use an event handler to run when the checkbox changes state

```js
    var 
       budget_1 = document.getElementById('budget_1'),
       itemize = document.getElementById('itemize');
     
    itemize.addEventListener("change", readonly);

    function readonly(){
        if (itemize.checked==false) {
            budget_1.readOnly = true;
        } else {
           budget_1.readOnly = false;
        }  
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="itemize"/>
<input type="text" id="budget_1" readonly/>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks your code worked!  Quick newbie question, is using addEventListener basically an easier/cleaner version of writing a function (i.e. myFunction) and then calling it in HTML through onchange script (i.e. <input onchange="myFunction()"/> )?

Comment: Hi, no I wouldn't say its easier / harder, however I much prefer to keep all the html / javascript in separate files. Its much cleaner and more professional. My attitude is, i wouldn't use inline styles, so why use inline js? although it basically achieves the same thing

Comment: thanks for your clarification.  I much prefer your way mentioned above.  I've been using the inline onChange way and it's actually much more confusing since they are all over the place.  thanks again.